# Returning "object" in scala

Tags: scala, object

I'm kinda new to scala. I got into trouble while trying to return object type.

Here is the code.

It shows "error: not found: type A"

```
object A{}

object B {
  def getInstance() : A = {
    return A
  }
}
```

If I do similar kind of thing with class instance, it wont show any problem.

```
class A{}

object B {
  def getInstance() : A = {
    return new A
  }
}
```

As far as I know object type is a singleton instance of class. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compiler complains that can not find type A because in your case A is a name of an object not a type, use A.type to refer to type, like this:

```
object A

object B {
  def getInstance: A.type = A
}
```

Comment: Just would like to add that with type inference you could actually omit return type and write just `def getInstance = A`

Answer (score 3):

Because `object` is a singleton is does not define a `type`, instead in defines a value.

If you would look at the Java equivalent, using scala `object` produces the:

```
A$ class //
A$.MODULE$ // singleton instance definition
```

The `type` is however masked and can be accessed via `A.type`.

Using `return` is also not necessary in Scala. The last statement position in a block is automatically interpreted as `return` value.

```
class A{}

object B {
  def getInstance() : A = new A
}
```